# Big O notation with Multiplicative Incremented For Loop

Tags: java, big-o

I have a question about the Big O notation of this code:

```
    public static void printItA(int n){
    for(int i=0; i< n; i++){
        for (int j = 1; j<n; j*=2){
            System.out.println("Something");
        }
      }
    }
```

It seems to me like the big O should be O(n^2), but the j*=2 part of the for loop confuses that for me. Can anyone clear this up for me?

Comment: `n*n/2` is still denoted as `O(n^2)`

Comment: If you experiment with the value of `n` you'll see that it will total in `O(nlogn)` iterations.

Comment: but the inner for loop wouldn't be O(n).... if anything, it would be logarithmic correct?

Comment: @breezee yes thank you for clearing that up

Answer (score 4):

Take an example of N = 16

Your outer loop will iterate 16 times.  `O(N)` i.e. linearly with your input.

Your inner loop will iterate 4 (1, 2, 4, 8, 16) times for each of outer loop. Your inner loop reduces the work by 2 on each iteration. `O(log n)`

So final runtime complexity `O(n * log(n))`